# jqgrid json url not working

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I am very new to Jquery and hence require your help in this regard.

I am trying to use jqGrid with JSON url but not able to use it. The htm page does not display any data.

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    $('#list').jqGrid({
        datatype: 'json',
        url: 'json_url',
        caption: 'Prospect Finder',
        gridview: true,
        height: "auto",
        colNames: ['Partner','First Name', 'Last Name', 'Organization'],
        colModel: [
            {name: 'PARTNER', jsonmap: 'PARTNER' },
            {name: 'NAME_FIRST',jsonmap: 'NAME_FIRST' },
            {name: 'NAME_LAST', jsonmap: 'NAME_LAST' },
            {name: 'NAME_ORG1', jsonmap: 'NAME_ORG1' }
        ],
        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: false,
            id: "PARTNER",
            root: function (obj) {
                return obj;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And this is my JSON data

```
{"itab":[ { "PARTNER":"0061000220", "NAME_FIRST":"", "NAME_LAST":"", "NAME_ORG1":"GTA Central" }, { "PARTNER":"0061000221", "NAME_FIRST":"", "NAME_LAST":"", "NAME_ORG1":"GTA West" }, { "PARTNER":"0061000222", "NAME_FIRST":"", "NAME_LAST":"", "NAME_ORG1":"GTA East" }, { "PARTNER":"0041000141", "NAME_FIRST":"", "NAME_LAST":"", "NAME_ORG1":"Office Systems" }  ]}
```

Can somebody plz help me ?

Thanks, DJ

Comment: you have an extra comma here `'NAME_ORG1' },` <--

Comment: How are you providing the json data to your jqgrid? Not sure but I think the hard coded "url:json_url" is the culprit?

Comment: @wirey : Ihave removed the extra comma, but the issue still persist.

Comment: @gaurav, the url is not hard coded, its a proper server url whose json output I have displayed in my original query

Comment: what browser are you using?  If you're using chrome/firefox open up developer tools/firebug and check console for errors and check to make sure the request is completing successfully.. and you're getting the JSON in the response

Comment: @wirey Checked in chrome, No errors in Console and I am getting the JSON output, have validated in Jlint.

Comment: @user1596433 try changing jsonReader root to 'itab' because that is supposed to point to the array that contains the data.  or change the return to obj.itab

Comment: Have you checked that your JSON is valid? In my experience the jqGrid would be expecting more information in the JSON, Ex Total, page, records, and then rows.  I'm also unfamilar with the need for the JSON reader portion of your grid?, what are you building the JSON with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just fix the `root` property of `jsonReader` to `root: "itab"`. Additionally it's important to include `rowNum` with some large enough value (like `rowNum: 10000`). If you don't do this and don't use `pager` then jqGrid will just display only the first 20 rows from the server response (default value of `rowNum` is 20) and discard all other rows.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user1596433.htm) read the JSON data successfully and displays

[image]

It uses the following code

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    $('#list').jqGrid({
        datatype: 'json',
        url: 'user1596433.json',
        caption: 'Prospect Finder',
        gridview: true,
        height: "auto",
        colNames: ['Partner','First Name', 'Last Name', 'Organization'],
        colModel: [
            {name: 'PARTNER', width: 80 },
            {name: 'NAME_FIRST' },
            {name: 'NAME_LAST' },
            {name: 'NAME_ORG1', width: 100 }
        ],
        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: false,
            id: "PARTNER",
            root: "itab"
        },
        rowNum: 10000,
        autoencode: true,
        loadonce: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the docs. http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data
Your json is not setup correctly.
See

```
  { 
      "total": "xxx", 
      "page": "yyy", 
      "records": "zzz",
      "rows" : [
        {"id" :"1", "cell" :["cell11", "cell12", "cell13"]},
        {"id" :"2", "cell":["cell21", "cell22", "cell23"]},
          ...
      ]
    }
```

This is the default format (although you can override it but you still need to provide id, total, page and records)

```
jsonReader: {
    repeatitems: false,
    id: "Id",
    root: function (obj) { return obj.itab; },
    page: function (obj) { return 1; },
    total: function (obj) { return 1; },
    records: function (obj) { return obj.itab.length; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My experience is:

The table stuck on loading, which means it has attempted to retrieve from url, but cannot process it.

I then realized that my json is incompatible with the default jsonReader, solution is either

1.set jsonReader to be compatible with your json data

example json data:

```
{"page":1,"YOUR_ROW_NAME":[{"YOUR_ID":"14","YOUR_CELL_NAME":["ImageHeight"]}]}
```

add following to javascript (other keys (i.e page), can also be overridden)

```
jsonReader : { 
      root: "YOUR_ROW_NAME",  
      cell: "YOUR_CELL_NAME", 
      id: "YOUR_ID", 
},
```

2.carefully use default jsonReader, must use "rows",'id','cell' inside square brackets [] while encoding data

```
foreach($all as $row){
    $response->rows[$i]['id']=$row->id;
    $response->rows[$i]['cell']=array($row->id,$row->name,$row->url);
    $i++;
}
```

useful wiki for starters: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data